# What is a good synonym for "badass" that would be usable in a high school setting?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm looking for a better way to say "orchestral brass musicians are badass" that doesn't use any words that could be considered profanity.

(If you're not sure what I mean by orchestral brass musicians, as far as I'm concerned they're the equivalent of Samuel L. Jackson.)

Comment: Just say "baaaaad" followed with a wry smile and then arched eyebrows.

Comment: He's a bad mother-shut yo mouth.

Comment: Just do it. Don't be complicit in your own bowdlerization.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to help trombonists to that extent. I mean, come on.

Comment: Is _brass_ a euphemism here for _badassium?_

Comment: -1 How is this Q. thriving when it came with no homework in the first place?

Answer (score 13):

These terms can vary a bit by region and trendiness as well as vulgarity, but some possible alternatives:

wicked
bangin'
hard-core
bitchin'
fierce
warriors

Comment: Also, my personal favourite: Awesome!

Comment: How about fawesome?

Comment: +1 for [hardcore](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-mPnmfrm6I).

Comment: @Loquacity: I had awesome in my list, then decided it didn't have the edge that @NReilingh was looking to keep.

Comment: _Bitching_ means _excellent_ or _extremely_: _a bitching new album_; _it's bitchin' hot, ain't it?_

Comment: fabulous, tremendous or just great :)

Answer (score 1):

Orchestral brass musicians are the [*shiznit*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shiznit).

Comment: by they way, shiza - is shortened from schizophrenia (russian folks will approve)

Comment: I can't believe I'm the first person to upvote you on this.  If nothing else, it gave me a good laugh.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Our horns are smokin'!
- Our horns are the bomb, baby!
- These horns kick brass!
- We've got brass . . . balls!

Answer (score 0):

Orchestral brass musicians play
higher
faster
louder

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can get credit for supplying you with a link, but I stumbled upon your post while looking for a Russian equivalent to this word and my searches led me down a lot of different nooks and crannies to include this page right here:

[**Power Thesaurus entry for "badass"**](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/badass)

Either way, I do realize I'm a bit late to this party, but hope it helps someone just the same.

By the way, I didn't look to see if "the bomb" was on the Power Thesaurus list, but if not, there's another one for you.  (I see now that Kristina Lopez beat me to the punch on that one, but I second her suggestion.)