# Formal synonym for "badass" as a noun

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23368/52446) discusses formal synonyms for "badass" as an adjective, but I am asking for a noun usable in a somewhat formal setting with the same connotation and meaning. A single word would be preferable, but a short phrase is acceptable.

Comment: @TimLymington there are two problems with the duplicate question First, it's closed; second there is only one answer upvoted. If questions that are closed can be nominated as duplicates I might reconsider but frankly the answers suggested there are not very inspiring, which is perhaps also telling.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: neither of those seems to me a good reason to have two identical questions cluttering up the site. By all means vote to reopen the other one and/or suggest to the mods that they should be merged: but you can't keep asking the same question just because you don't like the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what formal means because I could formally use badass as a noun.

Formal professions would include soldier, gladiator, fighter...

And you could take it to a new level and call them champ(ion), savior, god...

"That dude is a god" - sounds badass to me.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would show admiration for a badass in a formal setting by saying something like "Joe Bloggs is pretty indomitable"

> ### indomitable
>
> *impossible to defeat or discourage*
>
> Full Definition of INDOMITABLE
>
> *incapable of being subdued :  unconquerable*

or perhaps

> ### bodacious
>
> *A combination of the words bold and audacious; excellent, admirable, or attractive*

Obviously the latter is also US informal but removes the "ass" element.

Answer (score -2):

Here are some alternatives :

*ruffian, bully, churl, oaf, and lout*

*Churl* would suit the description.

Comment: Could you explain why *churl* fits? Provide a quote or a link that strengthens your answer?

Answer (score -3):

Consider [**scalawag**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scalawag), [**scoundrel**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scoundrel+?s=t), and [**rascal**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rascal?s=t).

Comment: Badass does not equal bad.